# Oh-my-zsh hash (pound) symbol bad pattern or match not found

Tags: hash, key, zsh

I'm quite sure is something dealing with my Oh-my-zsh configuration, but I can't figure out what it is.

When I use a "#" symbol in my git command (but on everything else too, like 'ls #2' for instance) I get 'bad pattern' error or 'no match found'

I guess is about counting something, but I can't find where to configure it.

I.E.

```
➜  demo git:(adlist) git push origin adlist#3 
zsh: no matches found: adlist#3
```

or

```
➜  demo git:(adlist) git push origin #3-adlist
zsh: bad pattern: #3-adlist
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
git push origin 'adlist#3'
git push origin #3-adlist
```

In zsh `#` is used for pattern removal. See: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html under the heading *Standard forms: pattern removal*

Comment: Is it possible to disable pattern removal? This is driving me nuts

Comment: The linked article doesn't really explain what use of `#` (without quoting) actually causes `zsh` to try to *do*. Can anyone put it into concise english?

Comment: Pattern removal. Try: param=foobar;
echo ${param#foo}

Comment: @SWrobel you can disable it by aliasing git with noglob git: alias git='noglob git'

Comment: @swrobel also you can use `set -k`

Comment: @maxymoo Do you know how to undo `set -k` ?

Comment: @YonggooNoh `set +k`

Comment: The explanation in the accepted answer is wrong. Pattern removal applies to parameter substitutions. But the question has no parameter substitution. `#` also has 2 different special meanings in globbing. See the man page `zshexpn` under "Glob operators" and "Globbing flags".

Answer (score 11):

You can `unsetopt EXTENDED_GLOB`, and this should stop `#` being interpreted as a part of a pattern.

If you really want to keep most of the features of `EXTENDED_GLOB`, but want to disable `#` being used for patterns, then you can `disable -p '#'` (you have to single quote the `#` argument, so that it doesn't get expanded like a pattern). This certainly works in my zsh installation, version 5.7.1, even though it is not documented in [zshbuiltins(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins).

Answer (score 2):

Open your zshrc file:

```py
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Add into end of file:

```py
unsetopt INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS
unsetopt BAD_PATTERN
```

Effect your file:

```py
source ~/.zshrc
```

Restart your terminal and enjoy it.

Comment: answers should have more reasoning as to what something is doing and why you are suggesting something