# git checkout gives zsh: no matches found:

Tags: git, zsh, special-characters

My colleague created a branch. I am trying to checkout to the branch.

```
git checkout hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside
```

The terminal returns

```
zsh: no matches found: hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside
```

If I do `git branch -r`, I can see the remote branch does exist:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside
  origin/master
```

Why am I getting `no matches found`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13783754/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzsh%5D+hash+symbol

Comment: This is purely a zsh issue; it has nothing to do with Git.

Comment: @phd : _pattern removal_ can't explain this IMO, because we are not inside a `${....}` parameter expansion, where the `#` indeed would have a special meaning.

Comment: @RaphaelPinel : Can't reproduce your issue (with zsh 5.8). Do you get the same error when you do a `echo` instead of a `git checkout`? What is your zsh version?

Comment: @user1934428 I also have zsh 5.8 and yes I am getting the same error 'no matches found' if I try ```echo echo stringwithhash#``` I get ```zsh: no matches found: stringwithhash#```

Answer (score 11):

It turns out I need to put quotes around the branch name if it contains a special character like a hash sign #

with `git checkout 'hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside'`
I get now:

```
Branch 'grzegorz/configureAWSAmplify_#PROAP-320' set up to track remote branch 'hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'hisName/branchNameWithAHash#Inside'
```

I tested only 'single quotes' but I think "double quotes" should work as well.

Thanks @user1934428
to your comments and links @phd it seems to be an issue with my zsh config.
Entering `unsetopt EXTENDED_GLOB` fixed the issue.

Now if I enter `echo stringwithhash#`   I am getting `stringwithhash#` whereas before it was `zsh: no matches found: stringwithhash#`

Comment: Of course quoting helps, but this does not explain, why in your concrete case quotes are needed. Depending on your settings, a `#` either introduces a comment or is just a normal character. `#` gets special treatment in globbing flags, but in this case , there should be parenthesis around it, such as `(#q:.....)`. Even then you would have to turn on _extended globbing_ explicitly.

Comment: Ah, `extended_glob` was the culprit! On first reading of your posting, my first idea was indeed that you had enabled this, but then I read the man page and could not find an explanation, that extended globbing would affect the string _you_ had in your example. Indeed, as I am rereading the _zshexpn_ man page right now, I can not find it.  Do you? If not, maybe you could ask a new question, asking what `#` is doing with extended globbing on the pattern you have.

Comment: @user1934428 I am not an advanced zsh user, never opened the manual and I don't remember to have ever activated ```extended_glob```, so it must have been there by default. Recently upgraded to Big Sur, don't know it it is related.

Comment: 'extended_glob' is off by default. You must have turned it on in one of the startup files. It could be possible that Apple has this setting in its system wide startup files, but I consider this highly unlikely. In any case, you can research this by running a `zsh -xl` and analyze the output, where this option is set. Maybe some other unwanted settings are done as well, so it would be useful to check for this reason too.

Comment: BTW, I start to wonder whether this is maybe even a bug in zsh. Not even the man page mentions it, but also none of the tutuorial pages on extended zsh globbing which I found, seems to know this feature. BTW, a quite good overview of extended globs is [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_2.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error while adding helm repo on my macOS like the following:

```
helm repo add chart-alias-name git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo-name@chart/path?ref=ref-tag

> zsh: no matches found: git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo-name@chart/path?ref=ref-tag
```

and I have fixed the problem by adding quotes around the full git URL like the following:

```
helm repo add chart-alias-name "git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo-name@chart/path?ref=ref-tag"
```